# Power Supply with Short Circuit Protection

Tags: power-supply, power, short-circuit

a Power Supply with Short Circuit Protection that Automatically turn Off when Shorted and automatic resumes its function if not shorted without using any switches. thus anyone know how to build this? or do you have any idea how to build it?

Comment: There are lots of shot circuit protection circuits with discretes in web using BJTs and MOSFETs...just google

Comment: can you give me some circuits that has short circuit protection? or just a short circuit protection circuit.

Comment: 1. http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php/137170-current-limiting-circuit-opinions                                    2. http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php/124203-I-need-a-discrete-voltage-independent-current-limiting-circuit                                                      3.  http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/transistor_current_limiter/transistor_current_limiter.php                      Searching "Current limit with discretes" yielding good results with google. LM317 based one, Simple BJT current limiter...etc

Answer (score 1):

This function is built in to almost any commercially available laboratory power supply as well as most other supplies.  Most simply, the voltage generated by a current sensing resistor is fed back to the regulating circuit and will shut it down if the current is too high (this generally is designed to provide current limiting as well as short circuit protection).  Look at the schematic of any lab power supply or search on Short Circuit Protection for more details.